# ReactJs bootstrap modal with dynamic body

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am working on a website where login, register and forgot password popups will appear alternatively (not at a time). So I want to create a modal with multiple body content components.

But I am unable to figure out how to display those. When I click on login or register button Modal content is attaching to modal, but not displaying

Footer.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ModalTemplate from './modals/ModalTemplate'

class Footer extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (<><ModalTemplate /></>)
 }
}

export default Footer
```

Footer.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import LoginModalBody from './modals/LoginModalBody'
import RegisterModalBody from './modals/RegisterModalBody'

class Header extends Component {
 Login() {
  ReactDOM.render(<LoginModalBody />, document.getElementById('common_modal_content'));
 }
 Register() {
  ReactDOM.render(<RegisterModalBody />, document.getElementById('common_modal_content'));
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div className='fd bg_Header height_100vh p_5'>
    <div className='mainSize'>
     <div className="fd">
      <div className="row m_0 p_tb_15">
       <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <img className="logoSize" src={Constants.Application.PUB_URL + "/img/logo.svg"} />
        <img src={Constants.Application.PUB_URL + "/img/icons/menu.svg"} className="float-right m_r_15 pointer menuIcn"
         width="30px" />
       </div>
       <div className="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
         <span className="pointer" onClick={this.Login}>LOGIN
         </span> | <span className="pointer" onClick={this.Register}>REGISTER </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Header
```

ModalTemplate.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class ModalTemplate extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (<> <div id="common_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" id="common_modal_content">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div></>);
 }
}
export default ModalTemplate;
```

LoginModalBody .js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class LoginModalBody extends React.Component {
 showModal() {
  document.getElementById('common_modal').classList.add('in')
  document.getElementById('common_modal').classList.add('show')
 }
 hideModal() {
  document.getElementById('common_modal').classList.remove('in')
  document.getElementById('common_modal').classList.add('hide')
 }
 componentDidMount() {

  this.showModal();
 }
 render() {
  return (<>
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div className="fd">

     <h6 className="p_t_15"><b>Log in continue</b></h6>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email address"
      className="fd m_t_15 form-control bck_ligrey bdr_0" />
     <input type="text" placeholder="Password"
      className="fd m_t_15 form-control bck_ligrey bdr_0 brdr_grey" />

     <div className="fd m_t_15">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <font color="#ddd">Remember My password</font>
      <p className="float-right font-12 m_0">Show password</p>
     </div>
     <button type="button" className="btn fd btn_orng font-12 m_tb_10"> Log in</button>
     <div className="fd  p_b_15 text-center">

      <a href="#"><u><b>Forgot password?</b></u></a>
     </div>
     
     <p className="fd m_b_10 m_t_30 text-center"><span className="font-10">Don't have an account?</span> <a
      href="#"><b>Sign Up</b></a></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </>
  );
 }

}

export default LoginModalBody;
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your modal component in separate file and import that in Footer or Header.

`const [content, setContent] = useState();` State for your content.

2. You need to create a function that will define which modal content you want to display. You can pass type as follows: `onClick={() => callModalComponent('login')}

Your function will be like:

```
const callModalComponent = (type: string) => {
   if(type === 'login'){
      setContent(<LoginComponent />) // set state content as per your form requirement
   } else if(type === 'register'){
      setContent(<RegisterComponent />) 
   }
   openModalContainer() // this will open your modal.
}
```

Comment: Hi Pratik, What will be in the openModalContainer()

Comment: Hey sorry, I missed one bracket. openModalContainer() is just a function which will open your modal. You can name if differently. The idea is you will set up modal content based on your condition and then you will call function to open modal.